# Questions about Android Keystore?

Tags: code-signing, keystore, signing, apk

Have few questions about Android/java Keystore...

- How the key file is created? i mean it depends on what?

When I use keytool on 2 different machines... why the resulted key file, is NOT the same size?
for example,  I used the same exact info (city / country...etc), as well as the password & validity...etc.. on 2 machine, and the key.store file is not having the same size.

- If i lose the key file... how can recreate another one (that may sign
  the same app APK)? is it linked to the machine on which it was
  generated?

or I can recreate it again if  I know the password and the information i wrote there...etc?

- To issue an update for an APK... should i use the same keystore on
  the same machine? or I can just re-use the keystore on a different
  machine?
- Is there is anything that I can/should do... to keep the private key
  secured? obviosuly other than using a hard password, and securing the
  file itself?

This code signing thing is a bit confusing to me, as all what I do is to run the command

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore C:\key.keystore -alias key_alias.keystore -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

but I wanted to really understand how it's done? and how it will affect my app in future?

Thanks.